# Is it possible to embed Python in PHP?

Tags: php, python, drupal

I work for a small tech start-up, and our main site is built on the CMS Drupal, which is a PHP-based CMS. However, I know some Python and would like to develop web applications to integrate with the website and allow users to interact with them.

How would I go about doing this? Does anyone have any experience or knowledge? Any particular module/script/etc that allows using Python or calling Python from PHP or Drupal?

Comment: You'd probably be better off learning a little PHP.

Comment: Haha, Ceejayoz. I will eventually, but I'm trying to pace myself. I wanted Python for my own projects (so I've been teaching myself), but once my boss found out I had even the littlest amount of programming knowledge, he's been encouraging me to work on projects for the business. I'm trying to make that happen as soon as possible without learning PHP immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to do integrate Drupal with external applications, but your best bet is probably installing the [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) in Drupal, and make calls from your Python app over HTTP, just as you would interact with a remote server.

Some other options:

- Interact directly with Drupal's database, rather risky as Drupal's database structure can change significantly with module upgrades or even configuration changes.
- Place the Python app within an iframe of a Drupal page, giving you Drupal's design, though no functional integration.
- Use JavaScript as a client-side middle-man between Drupal and Python.
- Use command line as a server-side middle-man between Drupal and Python. [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) would be useful here.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a few options!

Answer (score 4):

If you are developing a web application nothing stops you from using Python and making it accessible from a subdomain or path not used by drupal, just have the web server point to it. Ex:

```
http://mainsite.com/ <- drupal
http://app.mainsite.com <- python web app
http://mainsite.com/python/ <- python web app
```

This is fairly straight-forward with most web servers. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) might be particularly well suited for this, it has a nice feature which [can inspect live databases, and generate models for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/legacy-databases/):

```
python manage.py inspect.db > models.py
```

Which lets you interact with your existing database from Python with a nice ORM.

If you need to literally call Python from a PHP page, you can use [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) for fast IPC or TCP communication, or build a simple REST API, etc.

Comment: The question is whether the planned web app really needs to interact with the Drupal-managed content, and if so, in what ways and to what extent.